# Assume that $f,g \in L_{10}(\mu)$. Prove that their product $fg$ belongs to $L_5(\mu)$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

My question is this :

> Assume that $f,g \in L_{10}(\mu)$. Prove that their product $fg$ belongs to $L_5(\mu)$. State any theorems, lemmas or propositions from the course that you use.

So my inital though was to use Holder's inequality, and we get

$\int |fg|d\mu = (\int|f|^{10}d\mu)^{\frac{1}{10}}(\int|g|^{10}d\mu)^{\frac{1}{10}}$ and then to take this to this to the power of five in which case we get

$(\int |fg|d\mu)^{5} = (\int|f|^{10}d\mu\int|g|^{10}d\mu)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, but I am struggling about where to go from here.

Help!

Comment: You should start from $|fg|^5$, not from $|fg|$.

Comment: in which case I would have $\int|fg|^5 d\mu \leq (\int |f|^{50} d\mu \int |g|^{50} d\mu)^{\frac{1}{10}}$ - please elabourate :)

Comment: Apply Holder's inequality to the integral $\int |ab| d \mu$ with $a=|f|^5,b=|g|^5$, and $p=q=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f,g\in L_{10}(\mu)$ then by definition we have:
$$\Big(\int|f|^{10}\,d\mu\Big)^{1/10}<\infty\Leftrightarrow\int|f|^{10}\,d\mu<\infty$$
Similarly 
$$\Big(\int|g|^{10}\,d\mu\Big)^{1/10}<\infty\Leftrightarrow\int|g|^{10}\,d\mu<\infty$$
Define $\widetilde{f}:=f^5$ and $\widetilde{g}:=g^5$. Now to show that $fg \in L_{5}(\mu)$ it is equivalent to show that $\widetilde{f}\widetilde{g}\in L_1(\mu)$ since 
$$\int|fg|^5\,d\mu<\infty\Leftrightarrow\int |\widetilde{f}\widetilde{g}|\,d\mu<\infty$$
On the other hand we have $f,g\in L_{10}(\mu)$ which is equivalent to $\widetilde{f},\widetilde{g}\in L_2(\mu)$. 
But then by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality you have 
$$\Big(\int|fg|^5\,d\mu\Big)^2=\Big(\int |\widetilde{f}\widetilde{g}|\,d\mu\Big)^2\leq\int |\widetilde{f}|^2\,d\mu\int|\widetilde{g}|^2\,d\mu<\infty$$
The result the follows.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$|fg|^5=|f|^5 |g|^5\leq \frac{|f|^{10}+|g|^{10}}{2},$$
and integrating both sides gives you
$$\int |fg|^5d\mu\leq \frac12\left(\int|f|^{10}d\mu+\int|g|^{10}d\mu\right)<+\infty,$$
hence $fg\in L^5(\mu)$.

Alternatively, you can apply Cauchy's inequality to $f^5$ and $g^5\in L^2(\mu)$; this is more related to your original attempt.